# Calling method of multiple classes dynamically without inheritance in Java

Tags: java

Please look at the attached image. There are other no. of independent classes without any relation so no sense to make inheritance and I don't want to use too. Reflection doesn't help me too.

Suppose I have 20 classes, then I have to create 20 objects. If one is used, then 19 are useless.

So my question is that, Is there any way to do that by using single object that can cast to other objects.[image]

Comment: Please add comment before voting down.

Comment: I don't understand why having 20 classes would force you to create 20 objects. In any case, if they have similar methods that are going to be used in the same place, implementing an interface containing them is the obvious solution.

Comment: This is exactly what inheritance is for, be it class inheritance or interface inheritance. By stating that you "don't want to use inheritance" you're needlessly throwing out your greatest tool to solve this problem.

Comment: OK..OK..How can I forget about Interface!!!!

Comment: MightyPork you were the first to answer my * question. Just great..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an interface for example :

```
public interface IHello {

    public void sayHello();
}
```

Implementing the Interface :

```
public class Boy implements IHello {

    public void sayHello() {
        System.out.println("Hi from a boy");
    }
}

public class Girl implements IHello {

    public void sayHello() {
        System.out.println("Hi from a girl");
    }
}
```

Polymorphism:

```
IHello boy = new Boy();
IHello girl = new Girl();

boy.sayHello();
girl.sayHello();
```